# Android Studio - drawable folder missing?

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

I am using Android Studio version 1.2.2 and this how my res folder looks: 
[image: Res hierarchy]

As you can see there are no drawable folders present.
My concern:

1. Is the drawable has been deprecated and instead of it I have to place all the images used in the app in mipmap folders.
2. If I need to create the selectors or any shape for a view I need to place it in the "drawable"  or the "mipmap".

Does anyone has clue about it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Is the drawable has been deprecated and instead of it I have to place all the images used in the app in mipmap folders.

mipmap folders are for placing your app icons in only and in case of drawer folder, any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

You should go through [Google Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html) which says

"It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density."

2. If I need to create the selectors or any shape for a view I need to place it in the "drawable" or the "mipmap"

Just create drawer folder if you want to use selectors.

Answer (score 0):

if you are building different versions of your app for different densities, you should know about the "mipmap" resource directory. This is exactly like "drawable" resources, except it does not participate in density stripping when creating the different apk targets.

**But if you want to use selectors than you can create a drawable folder..**