# where drawable-hdpi ,drawable-mdpi ,drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi. go?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image]

before when I was creating a new project I was found this folders drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, and drawable-xxhdpi. but now they are all gone!

**is there any explanation of what happens?**

**and where we should put our images?**

Comment: You mean **drawable-xhdpi**. `Create it`.

Comment: yeah I know I can create it but I ask why google removed them from new project pre-created files

and wondering if they change the way we should put images in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perhaps because they will add an Gradle plugin that converts SVGs to PNGs during build (as mentioned in this [IO talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ihSQ44WO0&feature=youtu.be&t=2m46s)). The idea is that you will only need to have a single SVG instead of multiple PNGs for various densities (an thus, only one drawable folder). You can still create the folders and use PNGs.

The Gradle plugins for SVG conversion by Google has not been released yet, but you can use [Victor](https://github.com/trello/victor) or a similar plugin if you already want to use SVGs for your drawables.

Comment: Then we all hope that in a near future Android will finally support **real SVG**s, instead of `VectorDrawables`...

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Android Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html)
you can just create drawable-xhdpi.

I just give answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130199/android-studio-drawable-folder-missing/31130879#31130879)
 read and if any problem ask.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that Android Studio ever provided these dpi dependent drawable folders for the built-in default project scaffolding, and indeed, why should they?

Are they supposed to guess that you're going to support each and every one of these resolutions? Perhaps all your graphics will be vector graphics? Perhaps you only target low or high resolutions?

Also, the DPI modifier is only 1 of the possible modifiers you can attach to a resource folder. You can also add locale, screen width / height, mobile country code and many more. Should Android Studio create a folder with each of these options, along with every possible variation? You'd end up with thousands of folders which you'd likely never use.

In addition, creating a folder with no assets inside it is a big problem when you start synchronising your code using Github or something similar, and creating every possible folder with default assets inside seems like a huge waste.

I think the best approach here is to create any resource folder you need when you need it. Google leaves this decision to you.

Also, important: There is no XDPI or XXDPI folder - it's X**H**DPI, and XX**H**DPI

Comment: thanks, but yes they make these folders before they introduce mipmap and make them for app icon instead of drawable one.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your project section, Not in android section, If they gone just simply create them